# Preventing Google Maps from downloading unnecessary images/sprites

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I noticed that Google Maps API v3 downloads some unnecessary images/sprites even though I have all controls turned off and use a custom infoBox overlay.

Any way of avoding this?

Specifically, I'm talking about the png files imgs8, iw3 & undo_poly.. together they 'weigh in' at 20kB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't be bothered about these little images/sprites as map itself takes up much more space, so these images practically doesn't affect the total download time.